# How can I find the radiance over a finite range of wavelengths using Planck's Law?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

I'm working on a small programming project involving Planck's Law, and I keep getting errors. I'm fairly certain this is due to a misunderstanding of physics on my behalf.

Basically, I am trying to do numerical integration over a range of wavelengths (1nm to 10 000nm) for Planck's Law. I have a function written for this, and I am comparing the results with the Stefan Boltzmann Law results for the same temperatures.

I am working under the assumption that the radiance over the range of wavelengths from 1nm to 10 000nm will more or less approximate the total spectrum, as *spectral* radiance approaches zero quite quickly after ~5000nm. Is this a valid assumption...? I've been comparing the error ratios (Stefan Boltzmann "true" value / integrated "approximate" value) between the two functions (over a wide range of temperatures) and here is what they look like:

- 500K: 3.9795
- 1000K: 2.87267
- 1500K: 2.73022
- 2000K: 2.69029
- ...
- 9500K: 2.65730
- 10000K: 2.65723

As you can see, the Stefan Boltzmann Law result converges to be around 2.65 times higher than the integrated result as temperature increases. My theory on this is that I am severely under-estimating the amount of radiance accounted for in wavelengths between 10000nm and as it goes to infinity. As seen in this graph: [image]

As the temperature gets lower, the radiance in the range I'm checking (1nm to 10 000nm) presumably becomes a lower overall part of the total spectrum radiance. I think this may explain my higher ratios (i.e lower denominator, which is my approximate integration function) at lower temperatures? I cannot check this however, as I am not prepared to numerically integrate over an infinite range of wavelengths. Am I correct on this? If so, how can I (preferably computationally) conduct a definite integration of Planck's Law over a range of wavelengths?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

```
#include "Sunlight.h"
#include "Constants.h"
#include "si.h"


#include <iostream>


double Sunlight::spectrumPLNK(int temp_body, double wavelength){
    double spect_rad = ((2 * planck_c * pow(speed_light_c, 2)) / pow(wavelength, 5)) * 1 / (expm1((planck_c*speed_light_c) / (wavelength * boltzmann_c * temp_body)));
return spect_rad;
}


double Sunlight::integratePLNK(int temp_body, double n, double wave_len_low, double wave_len_high){
    double power = 0;

    double a = wave_len_low;
    double b = wave_len_high;

    double h = (b-a)/n;


    for(double i = 0; i<n; i++){
        power += spectrumPLNK(temp_body, a + i*h) + spectrumPLNK(temp_body, a + (i+1));
        std::cout << "New power: " << power << std::endl;
    }

    power *= h;

    std::cout << "Total spectrum power: " << power << std::endl;
    return power;
}

//**********************************************************************

double Sunlight::powerSBZL(int temp_body){
    double power_body = sigma_c* pow(temp_body, 4);

    std::cout << "Total SBL power: " << power_body << std::endl;
    return power_body;
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

```
double Sunlight::integratePLNK(int temp_body, double n, double wave_len_low, double wave_len_high){
    double power = 0;

    double a = wave_len_low;
    double b = wave_len_high;

    double h = (b-a)/n;


    for(double i = 0; i<n; i++){
        power += spectrumPLNK(temp_body, a + (i+1)*h);
    }

    power *= pi_c*h;

    std::cout << "Total spectrum power: " << power << std::endl;
    return power;
}
```

Comment: Your problem with the proportionality constant might be in the way you are trying to integrate over the wavelength, rather than the frequency. The volume element that is proportional to the energy in a band is proportional to $df$, not $d\lambda$. The transformation from frequency to wavelength will also distort the integration at the short end of the spectrum, I believe, because your sampling intervals are getting very crude.

Comment: What is the integration scheme you are using? It seems you are evaluating at `a+i*h` and `a+i+1` for `i=0:n`. That second part makes no sense at all. Did you mean `a + (i+1)*h` perhaps? Even that is not very good - but definitely better... I would highly recommend using something other than trapezoid - even Simpson's rule (1-4-2-4-2-...4-1) will deal better with the curvature than (1-2-2-2-2-...2-1).

Comment: Sorry @Floris, I have changed my integration method multiple times (trying to see if using better methods would yield substantially more accurate results). This was supposed to be trapezoid I believe. I tried Simpson's Rule earlier and there was no real difference in accuracy that I could see.

Comment: Do you see the error - you are using `(i+1)` instead of `(i+1)*h`...

Comment: Yes, I changed that. However, the error between my functions persists. This is odd, I feel as if I am missing a factor or something somewhere as you have mentioned in the comments on your answer.

Comment: What is the value of `n` in your code (defined in "constants.h" I assume?). This is rapidly becoming a debugging exercise. The code in my answer gives the same answer for both methods (and for discrete integration - not just for the built in library routines). You have not posted enough code for someone to reproduce your problem - at any rate, "debug my code" is not on topic here. But the scale factor of $\pi$ and the fact that yes, at low temperatures you need to extend your wavelength range, are the bits of physics I believe you needed. Right?

Comment: `n` is the number of intervals I am integrating over. I currently have this set to 100 000. I also apologize, my code is a bit of a mess (I am relatively new to programming), and I appreciate your help looking through it - I'll play around with it some more and try some better integration methods. And yes, those were primarily the physics questions I was looking to have answered. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it is hard to know where you went wrong. I did write a few lines of code myself to see what might be going on - and found that the values converge quite nicely as you approach higher temperatures (for the lowest temperatures of 500 K and 1000 K, significant amounts of energy do indeed extend beyond 10,000 nm).

**updated**
There is a small problem with scaling: the SB law gives radiation from a black body in W/m$^2$ which is different than Planck's Law which gives radiance per unit area, per steradian.

Now there is a modification for the SB law: if you divide the usual equation by $\pi$ you get the result in "per steradian" (see the Wiki article).

This gives me the following code snippet (Python - not my strongest language but it's good for this kind of thing because of the `scipy.integrate` functions which do a lot of the hard work; the built in physical constants and plotting routines are nice too):

```
# integrate Planck's Law and compare results with Stefan-Boltzman

from math import pow,exp,pi
from scipy.constants import codata
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# get physical constants we need:
D = codata.physical_constants
h = D['Planck constant'][0]
k = D['Boltzmann constant'][0]
c = D['speed of light in vacuum'][0]
s = D['Stefan-Boltzmann constant'][0]

def planck(l, T):
    # reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck's_law
    if (l <= 0):
        return 0  # no valid values <=0
    p = c*h/(k*l*T)
    if (p > 700):
        return 1e-99 # preventing under/overflow in the exp function
    else:
        return (2*h*c*c)/(pow(l, 5.0) * (exp(c*h/(k*l*T))-1))  # <<< fixed

def SB(T, emissivity = 1.0):
    #  Stefan-Boltzmann law : returns radiance = total power per steradian
    # reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan-Boltzmann_law
    return emissivity * s * pow(T, 4.0) / pi  # <<< expression "per steradian"

# T values to use:
Tvec = np.arange(500,10500, 500)

Planck_integrals=[]
SB_integrals=[]
max_wavelength = 10000*1e-9 # 10,000 nm
for T in Tvec:
    y,abserr = integrate.quad(planck, 0, max_wavelength, args=(T))
    Planck_integrals.append(y)
    SB_integrals.append(SB(T))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(Tvec, np.array(Planck_integrals)/np.array(SB_integrals))
plt.xlabel('Temperature (K)')
plt.ylabel('Ratio integral/SB value')
plt.title('Comparing direct integration and Stefan-Boltzmann - integrating 0-10 um')
plt.show()
```

And this plot:

[image]

I played around a bit with discrete integration to see if I can get the results to match (so you don't need to use existing libraries... although that's usually a really good idea). This was the result (using the same definition of functions `planck` and `SB` as before):

```
# stepwise integration
n = 1000
simpson = 0.
trapezoid = 0.
max_wavelength = 10000.0
min_wavelength = 0.
H = (max_wavelength - min_wavelength)/n
wavelength_scale = 1e-9
T = 2000.0

for i in range(n):
    if ((i==0) | (i == n-1)):
        w_trap = 1
        w_simpson = 1
    else:
        w_trap = 2
        if (i%2==0):
            w_simpson = 4
        else:
            w_simpson = 2
    wavelength = (min_wavelength + H * i) * wavelength_scale
    hp = H * planck(wavelength, T) * wavelength_scale
    trapezoid = trapezoid + hp * w_trap
    simpson = simpson + hp * w_simpson

print 'trapezoid: ', trapezoid / 2
print 'simpson: ', simpson / 3
print 'SB: ', SB(T)
```

This gave the following output:

```
trapezoid:  284606.470099
simpson:  284606.473505
SB:  288789.72548
```

Clearly the two integration methods give nearly the same result; and it's very comparable with the result from the Stefan-Boltzman formula. I have to conclude the error is in your integration formula (as I pointed out in my comment), and/or in extremely coarse sampling of the function. But even when I set `n=100` in the above I get comparable results...

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my post with my C++ code, and I have a small question about yours. I noticed in your planck() function, you return: "return (h*c*c)/(pow(l, 5.0) * (exp(c*h/(k*l*T))-1))". Isn't the Planck Function supposed to be (2*h*c*c), or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right - I will look more carefully and update. I was a bit puzzled about the $2\pi$ factor. In fact there is a "SB per steradian" function that has a factor $\pi$. Combined with the factor 2 you spotted we can clear this up. I will also include some comments on your code in the update.